# Package class scope in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm having some issues writing packages, perhaps someone can help.
I am trying to include new npm modules and add them into the Meteor class.

So for example in my package.js I have declared:

```
mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

This works fine, I can console log this and it shows the object.
However inside `Package.on_use(` I can't use the Meteor class: `Meteor is not defined`
 - I have even tried using the startup package before using the Meteor class with no look.

and

Inside a js file included using: `api.add_file` I can't get the mongoose class:  `mongoose is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

The solution as it seems is to use inside the add_file file:

```
var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require;
```

That way I can use the require in there.

---

Edit: This doesn't actually solve all use cases as it only runs server side, so either I need a solution that will work both client side and server side or a way to declare requires in the package folder and using its return value some how.